# How to permanently change the color of some elements?

Tags: jquery, json

I have a php page on which I want a user can change the color of some elements, and next time he load the page his choices should be loaded by default.

I'm using jQuery `click()` function to change the colors, and to save the changes on server side I suppose that the best way is using jquery/json, but I'm totally new about this.

Should I have a separate json file with color options stored? I found so many stories on web about jquery/json, but still need an example how to accomplish this task. Please help with a useful link or code example.

```
 #div01 {
        background:#008080;
        color:#ffffff;
    }


$('#btnBlue').click(function () {
    $('#div01').css('background', '#0000ff');
    $('#div01').css('color', '#ffffff');
});

$('#btnRed').click(function () {
    $('#div01').css('background', '#ff0000');
    $('#div01').css('color', '#0000ff');
});
```

Comment: Cookie? Any reason why not?

Comment: @JNF maybe the reason could be - the user can delete the cookies (reinstalling the OS, for example) and loose the color settings on my site.

Comment: He can, but that is usually considered an acceptable risk. For the once in a dog's lifetime a user reinstalls the OS - the user would understand the need to reconfigure a few things.

Comment: @JNF, at the and of the day, I think you're right. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a concrete example on how to do this, this might do the trick.
First, use this JavaScript library: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie.

Then, this would be your script:

```
var backgroundColor = $.cookie('backgroundColor'), color = $.cookie('color');
$('#div01').css('background', backgroundColor);
$('#div01').css('color', color);

$('#btnBlue').click(function () {
    $.cookie(backgroundColor, '#0000ff');
    $.cookie(color, '#ffffff');
    $('#div01').css('background', backgroundColor);
    $('#div01').css('color', color);
});

$('#btnRed').click(function () {
    $.cookie(backgroundColor, '#ff0000');
    $.cookie(color, '#0000ff');
    $('#div01').css('background', backgroundColor);
    $('#div01').css('color', color);
});
```

Comment: Campari, thanks a lot for your link, and especially for the code example. I will try. Sounds as a solution.

Answer (score 4):

You need to persist the state of those elements somewhere, without that it is not possible.

To persist the state, you need to determine whether to use a client side storage or server side persistence.

If you want to store the data only within the browser, then you can think of either cookie or html5 localStorage, but the drawback is once it is set all the users using the browser will get the updated state.

If you have user tracking in the site then you may have to use a server side persistence to store the state in relation with the current user

Comment: Arun, I would prefer to store the settings on server side. Does it mean that I must have a database?

Comment: @SunSky yes, you will have to use some kind of storage in the server... need not be a RDBMS

Comment: @SunSky but do you have user tracking in your site

Comment: obiously u should have something for storage either be some text file or db or any thing that sits on the permanent memory @SunSky

Comment: Arun, no, I have no user tracking

Comment: @SunSky if you don't have user tracking, it is not possible to user a server side storage because you will not be able to identify a user

Comment: Arun, yess, I understand. What is the standard solution - to create a user tracking just for this task? Or... what? Cookies? Maybe Campari's solution ?

Comment: @SunSky enabling user tracking for only this seems too much... but it depends completely on the business requirement... if it is a nice if feature you can go with a cookie based solution